# WSO2 Tomcat deployment logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need your help.
How can I get logs in WSO2 EI while WAR is deploying?
I want to see the process and get the errors like in standalone Tomcat instance.
Is it possible?
I've tried to change log level at log4j.properties, catalina-server.xml and many others. But there is still no result.

Kind Regards,
Kirill

Comment: You can change the log4j.properties file

Comment: Hi! What should I change there? Which property is related to tomcat runtime logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the next solution:
In file /opt/ame-a/repository/conf/log4j.properties
set
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG
This way you will be able to implement logging realization inside your application and put application logs wherever you need, for example, I put it to
/opt/ame-a/lib/tomcat/logs/monitor.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to setthe log level in the logging-bridge.properties file.
Open **wso2as/repository/conf/etc/logging-bridge.properties** file and put `org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST`